# No permission to Clear a specific range with google-apps-script in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to clear a specific range of cells in a spreadsheet with the help of Google Apps Script and the Google-Spreadsheet-API, but I always get: 'you do not have the permission to call clear'.

This is the code I use:

```
function clearRange(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getActiveRange().clear();
}
```

The script is created with the help of the script-editor (opened from inside the spreadsheat on which I would like to use this method).
So all are created under the same account.

Do I have to do something else?

Comment: I tried it out. It asked for me to authorize and then ran as expected. Is there more to it than you have described? How are you calling the function from the spreadsheet or is it being called by another function or script?

Comment: It didn't ask me to authorize and I don't see where I can do this afterwards. I call this method in a simple cell as: =clearRange()

Comment: Did you create the spreadsheet and the script?

Comment: I apologize for not completely reading your last comment. This cannot be called from a custom function.

Comment: You would need to create a button or menu item then select the range you want to clear and then click the button or choose the menu item or run it from the script manager.

Comment: THat is not what I hoped, but I can understand as the custom function can only change itself. I hope it can work with a trigger. I would like it to be cleared without manual clicking.

Comment: I see no problem with running using a trigger though you will have to specify the range in the script instead of getActiveRange()

Comment: You will need to run it at least once from the script editor to authorize.

Comment: Thanks for your help ScampMichael. I understand now why it didn't work and what the alternatives are.

Comment: ScampMichael suggest you put your comment in the answer box, looks like the right answer to me.

Comment: ScampMichael, if you put your command in the answer box, I can give you a positive vote ;)